# Producer-Consumer with Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, producer-consumer

Suppose I have a "producer-consumer" problem: the producer sends messages to the consumer and the consumer processes them asynchronously using Scala `Futures`: for instance `future { /* do the processing */ }`.

Suppose now that the producer produces 100 messages per sec. but the consumer processes only 10 messages per sec. What will happen ? I guess there will be a memory leak. There will be a lot of `Future` objects and the internal message queue of the thread pool will grow as well. Does it make sense ?

What is the best way to handle it ?

Comment: Note - I was confused by this - this question is about Futures and not actors.

Answer (score 2):

In akka, an execution context is used but there appears to be no mailbox - it would be worthwhile to read the source but I can answer your question by experimentation:

Future's do not have a 'mailbox' and I'm not 100% sure exactly what Akka does under the hood or what the execution context actually contains, but we can see that akka will run out of memory when using futures directly:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global                  ^

scala> while(1==1) Future(Thread.sleep(100))
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

If we're talking about messages, then there is a mailbox that describes the behaviour of the actor message queue (which would fill as only one message is processed at a time) - I'll explain this below.

Assuming a bounded mailbox (eg one with a size limit) what happens to the messages.
The answer is it depends on the mailbox.
First, a bounded mailbox has a few settings, such as size limit:

```
bounded-mailbox {
  mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedMailbox"
  mailbox-capacity = 1000
  mailbox-push-timeout-time = 10s
}
```

Now when that limit is hit, akka will either drop the old or the new messages depending on how the mailbox is configured - eg with this setting

```
# whether to drop older items (instead of newer) when the queue is full
discard-old-when-full = on
```

Obviously if there are other resource issues like out of memory then your application can crash meaning that the messages will be lost as they are stored in memory. An unbounded mailbox will continue to stack messages until error conditions occur which is why you may want to use bounded mailboxes.

If the loss of messages in error conditions in undesirable, there is another option = a durable mailbox can be used which will store the messages somewhere more persistent such as in a file. Here is an example mailbox configuration that uses a file for more durable message storage.

```
akka {
  actor {
    mailbox {
      file-based {
        # directory below which this queue resides
        directory-path = "./_mb"

        # attempting to add an item after the queue reaches this size (in items)
        # will fail.
        max-items = 2147483647

        # attempting to add an item after the queue reaches this size (in bytes)
        # will fail.
        max-size = 2147483647 bytes

        # attempting to add an item larger than this size (in bytes) will fail.
        max-item-size = 2147483647 bytes

        # maximum expiration time for this queue (seconds).
        max-age = 0s

        # maximum journal size before the journal should be rotated.
        max-journal-size = 16 MiB

        # maximum size of a queue before it drops into read-behind mode.
        max-memory-size = 128 MiB

        # maximum overflow (multiplier) of a journal file before we re-create it.
        max-journal-overflow = 10

        # absolute maximum size of a journal file until we rebuild it,
        # no matter what.
        max-journal-size-absolute = 9223372036854775807 bytes

        # whether to drop older items (instead of newer) when the queue is full
        discard-old-when-full = on

        # whether to keep a journal file at all
        keep-journal = on

        # whether to sync the journal after each transaction
        sync-journal = off

        # circuit breaker configuration
        circuit-breaker {
          # maximum number of failures before opening breaker
          max-failures = 3

          # duration of time beyond which a call is assumed to be timed out and
          # considered a failure
          call-timeout = 3 seconds

          # duration of time to wait until attempting to reset the breaker during
          # which all calls fail-fast
          reset-timeout = 30 seconds
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation but my question was about `futures`. I _guess_ that when I write `future { ... }` I actually create an object and put the object reference into the thread pool mailbox. Does it make sense ?  If it does I would ask if the mailbox is bound and what happens with `future { ... }` if the mailbox is full.

Comment: Ah yes - I'm sorry - the use of the term mailbox made me think this was an akka question.

Comment: I was confused because all of the other answers are talking about actor/dispatcher but you're talking about Future's specifically.

Comment: The answer is - you will run out of memory - I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the maximum queue size. In fact, I *think* Akka actors have limited queues by default, though I can well be wrong here.

That doesn't really solve the problem, but, in the end, if you don't have enough backend actors to do the processing, you won't be able to process everything.

I like what Netflix does: all requests go through proxies which monitor the health of the backend. If the backend is taking too long, they drop the request and serve a fallback: either a sensible default, or an error message. They talk a lot about their architecture, see [this presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Netflix-Architecture) for instance.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose now that I have a limited queue between the producer and consumer. Does it solve the problem ? Would not you change the consumer logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Have multiple consumers - use an actor pool. You can have it dynamically re-size according to the stress on the pool. See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I cannot add more actors/threads. For instance, the processing is CPU-bound and I have only 1 CPU.

Comment: Then you will exhaust your resources at some point. If you produce more then you can consume you will have to drop messages at some point (use a bounded queue with a size limit as Daniel suggested). Or use more resources, maybe a clustered approach (see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/common/cluster.html)

Comment: Suppose I have only one host with only one CPU. Suppose also that the producer and consumer work fine _in average_. The problem is to handle _bursts_. If a burst is bigger than planned then the consumer is allowed to throw away some messages. I know how to implement it with threads and blocking bounded message queue. Now I wonder how to implement with `scala.concurrent.future`.

Comment: Use akka, it gives you much more. See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/mailboxes.html